# cannot connect to database using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, database-connection

I know this sounds so repost several times. But I cannot get it resolved.

I tried to connect my application to mysql, these are what I have tried (I tried only one out of these options, not both):

1. `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');` on `application\config\autoload.php`, but I got `Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /Users/zakkafm/Sites/CodeIgniter/application/models/My_models.php on line 15`
2. `$this->load->database();` on `application\models\My_models.php` on `__construct()` (also I added `parent::__construct()`, but I got `Fatal error: Call to a member function database() on a non-object in /Users/zakkafm/Sites/CodeIgniter/application/models/My_model.php on line 7`

So, what could be wrong here?

EDIT:
this is my `database.php` looks like.

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'trial';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

RESOLVED!!!

After all, this is all because of the autocomplete on Eclipse I added on `system/core/Controller.php` and `system/core/Model.php`.

Comment: I believe you were fine autoloading it but there is an issue in your My_model, could you please update with the contents?

Comment: problem solved! please read my "RESOLVED" part on the post.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.., I think you don't have to add

```
$this->load->database();
```

on your My_models.php, coz as I know it will be automatically connected to the database as you  set on the database.php file. So, remove it from My_models.php file & try again.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: No use... I put those two as options, so I either added the autoload or the load->database inside my model.

Comment: So, you try to connect to 1 database with 2 database connection options (automatically & manually) ? If i'm not mistaken, if you're using 2 different databases, you could manually load the database as you have done with pconnect set to FALSE.

Comment: don't go too far for two databases, even I can't connect to a single database :)

Comment: Yup,, I know that :). If so, for testing the database connection, remove $this->load->database() from your My_models.php. Does it work?

Comment: still doesn't work... stop telling me about this thing... when I tried one of the two options, I commented the other :) yet still error

Comment: Ok, I think it would be more clear if you show the snippet code of your controller & model file, so we can trace the root cause of this problem. And also, what version of CI you're using? I've used 1.7.2 & 2.1.0 version & I've never get the database connection problem, hmm..

Answer (score 0):

In you `My_models.php` you shouldn't be calling `$this->load->database();` should just have:

```
class My_models extends CI_Model {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function something(){
    // your model code goes here
    }

}
```

Also you only need to enable the `autoload` and you are good to go (keeping in mind that the **MYSQL** library needs to be loaded for PHP.

And you might have an error here (don't see your code so not sure):

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in      
/Users/zakkafm/Sites/CodeIgniter/application/models/My_models.php on line 15
```

Comment: the error is exactly the error I had when using autoload... note that, those two numbers are options, so I used either first or second...